# ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC in detail view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class name `Flight`.
And I want to use this class (`flight`) with an extra field called `count`.
I created a `ViewModel` like below :

```
public IEnumerable<Departure> Departures { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Airline> Airlines { get; set; }
public int count { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
```

`flights` has 3 other classes in it.

But I cant use this view model in my detail view :

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.flight.Departure.Name)
```

and this is my get method :

```
public ActionResult Add(int id)
{
    var flight = db.Flights.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);

    if (flight == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var viewModel = new BuyViewModel
    {
        Flights = db.Flights.ToList(),
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And I got error:

> 'BuyViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'flight' and no
>   extension method 'flight' accepting a first argument of type
>   'BuyViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Comment: *and I got error*. What is the error message?

Comment: IF you could paste the error message someone could help you out on that. Without that it seems almost impossible.

Comment: 'BuyViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'flight' and no extension method 'flight' accepting a first argument of type 'BuyViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well it's not `flight` it is `Flights`.

Comment: how can I use my viewmodel in view?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You have `IEnumerable<Flight>`, you're saying you want `Flight` to have a property `Count`. Is this correct? Then you're in the wrong class.

Comment: `Flights` is a collection - you need to iterate over it - `@foreach (var flight in Model.Flights) { @Html.DisplayFor(m => flight.Departure.Name) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your `ViewModel` has not a property named `flight` and it is `Flights` and secondly you should don't use `Model` as parameter in your lambda expression because it hides the `Model` property of the page.

Also please note that `Flights` is of type `IEnumerable<Flight>` and so you can't access to the `Departure` property. You should either change the type of the `Flights` to `Flight` and then:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Flights.Departure.Name)
```

Or if you still want it to be `IEnumerable` then you can do something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Flights.Select(c => c.Departure).FirstOrDefault().Name)
```

Or iterate over `Flights`:

```
@foreach (var flight in Model.Flights) 
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(m => flight.Departure.Name) 
}
```

Comment: @leman17 Did you still get the same error? Or different error?

Comment: 'IEnumerable<Flight>' does not contain a definition for 'Departure' and no extension method 'Departure' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Flight>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)